# Upgrade to Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mac, upgrade, xcode, osx-mountain-lion

I was wondering if upgrading from Lion 10.7.4 to Mountain Lion 10.8 would wipe out all of my dependencies in /etc and others;

I ask because I have quite a few RoR projects each with different gem requirements and I'd hate to lose the delicate ecosystem I've set up, on account of an upgrade :/

Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: I would backup this information.

Comment: You probably shouldn't upgrade your OS without known good backups in any case, `/etc` or not...

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded to Mountain Lion few days ago and didn't lose my rails project & postgres database. However 3 things didn't work properly anymore — git, homebrew, and imagemagick.

Here's what I did to fix those three:

1. Install Command Line Tools from the XCode preference menu.
2. [Fixed Homebrew](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/27985816073/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-riding-a-mountain-lion).
3. Run `brew uninstall imagemagick` and install it back again with `brew install imagemagick`.

Comment: I had to do all three of those as well. X11 is no longer installed by default, so some Homebrew formulas required [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing).